# How to delete hyperlink from cell in phpexcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am trying to edit a sheet and delete rows, when I do so, the cells with an email address (with a mailto hyperlink) retain the hyperlink although the cell values are replaced by new cell shifting into its place.

For example 
cell A1 has email address abc@abc.com, cell A2 had a blank cell, when I delete row 1 using $sheet->removeRow fucntion, the row gets deleted, however A1 now is a blank cell with a mailto link to abc@abc.com

I an unable to delete this hyperlink on the cell using phpexcel

I have tried the following

1. `$cell->getHyperlink()->setUrl();`
2. `$cell->setHyperlink(new PHPExcel_Cell_Hyperlink(''));`

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you want to remove all of the links, or just one link?

Comment: I am happy to remove all or one,, anything that works really :)

Comment: can you try $cell->setHyperlink(null);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the value null in to the setHyperlink method against the cell

From looking at the code, this finds the worksheet the cell is attached to and removes the hyperlink if the value is null

```
$cell->setHyperlink(null);
```

Worksheet.php https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/Worksheet.php#L2702

Cell.php https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/Cell.php#L461

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation the following code will be used to add hyperlink

`$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E26', 'www.phpexcel.net');`

`$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('E26')->getHyperlink()->setUrl('http://www.phpexcel.net');`
Same Like Try the below code

`setUrl` `Empty` or `Null` Value.

`$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E26', '');`

`$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('E26')->getHyperlink()->setUrl('');`

Comment: only null removes the link, as Brett advised it first, I have marked his answer correct

Comment: thanks@user2636664. i mentioned to try both Null or Empty

Comment: I am aware of that and appreciate the effort you have put in. Thanks again